# what does "column stride field" mean regarding "doc values " in elasticsearch/lucene

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

Maybe someone here can shed some light on exactly what does it mean that **doc values** are stored inside the disk in "**column stride fashion**"

> Doc values are the on-disk data structure, built at document index time, which makes this data access pattern possible. They store the same values as the _source but in a column-oriented fashion that is way more efficient for sorting and aggregations. Doc values are supported on almost all field types, with the notable exception of analyzed string fields.

(taken from [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.5/doc-values.html)  )

From what I understand , **elasticsearch** has two major data structures , one is 
**"inverted index** , which is a mapping from a **term** to **document ids** that has this term , and second structure is "doc value" that is a mapping from **document id** to its fields values ?
Is that correct ?

But what does it mean to store it in **column-like fashion**? why is it efficient for sorting and aggregation ? what is "**row stride fashion**" ?

Maybe a visualization of this would help to demonstrate ?

Thanks a lot for the help

Comment: Thanks for posting this. I am yet to come across a nice document that explains Lucene DocValue in a simple term.